# Prevent insertion of invalid characters to text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, user-input

I have a form with standard text elements:

```
<form id="f">
    <input type="text" name="from" pattern="^[A-Za-z ]+$>
    <input type="text" name="to"   pattern="^[A-Za-z ]+$>
</form>
```

And I'd like to prevent users from entering disallowed characters into them. For example, typing <kbd>`0`</kbd> should have no effect.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#f input[type=text]").keypress( function(e) {
    new_text = $(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(e.which)
    pattern = $(this).attr("pattern")
    return Boolean(new_text.match(pattern))
})
```

The code works by returning false, and thereby cancelling the keypress, if the new text does not match `pattern`. It's important to use `function(e)` instead of `(e) =>` because the latter would bind `this` lexically, whereas we want to let jQuery bind `this` to the respective `input` element.